# Git - rename files with illegal characters

Tags: windows, git, escaping, file-rename

Our team works on repository which includes one directory where there are files with pipe character "|". I'm the only one on Windows so pipe character is illegal for files names.

1. Is there a way to rename files in the directory "extra" from ex. "2021|08|05" to "2021\08\05" when I make "git pull"?
2. Is there a way to rename files in the directory "extra" from ex. "2021\08\05" to "2021|08|05" when I make "git push"?

Comment: Both the pipe and backslash seem like bad options. The standard separator for this date format is a dash. Can you rename the files for everybody?

Comment: Unfortunaelly I can't do that

Answer (score 5):

1. No.
2. No.

These are the right answers to the question you've asked, but the trick is, you've *asked the wrong question*.  Alas, the answer to the *right* question is: "yes, but it's a horrible solution".  The question is: **Is there a solution to the problem of bad / invalid characters in file names stored in Git commits?**

In the early days of Git, when it was a collection of shell scripts that only a few people could use successfully,  one would obtain new commits from elsewhere with `git fetch`, then read these commits into Git's *index* with `git read-tree`.

Git's index, which Git also calls the *staging area* or sometimes the *cache*, *can* hold these file names.  In fact, even on Windows, Git's index can hold files named `aux.h`, which Windows won't let you create.  The index has no folders either: it just has files with names with embedded (forward) slashes, such as `path/to/file`.  Git can hold two different files, one named `README` and one named `readme`, in its index.  WIndows can't have two different files whose name only differs in case.

So, Git's index / staging-area can hold these files just fine.  The problem comes when you go to *work with* the files.  Files that are *in* Git's index, are stored there in a special Git-only format, as what Git calls a *blob object*.  You cannot read or write a blob object directly.  You have to use yet more Git commands to do this.  It's terribly inconvenient.

To use Git *conveniently*, then, we normally don't use all the individual one-step-at-a-time internal Git operations: we use some sort of higher level, *user* oriented command, like `git checkout`.  We *check out* an *entire commit:* Git will find *all* the files that are stored in that commit, read them into Git's index, and copy out and expand all the internal Git-only blob objects into ordinary files, with ordinary file names.

This step—copying files *out* of Git's index, to make them usable—is where things go wrong, on Windows.  The file's name in Git's index is, say, `path/to/2021|08|05`.  Git recognizes that `path/to/` has to be turned into two *folders*, `path\` and `path\to\`, on Windows, so that Git can create a a file in the second folder.  **Unfortunately, Git has no way to remap the `2021|08|05` part.**  That part is going to *stay* `2021|08|05`, and as you have seen, Git *can't* create a file with that name: the OS just says "no".

What you *can* do, at this point, is drop down to those lower-level commands.  You can run:

```
git rev-parse :path/to/2021|08|05
```

perhaps with quotes if needed, depending on your shell:

```
git rev-parse ":path/to/2021|08|05"
```

This `git rev-parse` command will show the *blob hash ID* for the file.  You can then access the file's *contents* with:

```
git cat-file -p <hash>
```

which prints those contents to the standard output.  If your shell supports redirection, you can then redirect the output to a file whose name is your choice.  This lets you see and use the file's contents.

The `git cat-file -p` command can take the index path name directly, so:

```
git cat-file -p ":path/to/2021|08|05" > path/to/2021-08-05
```

is a way to extract the file to a usable name.

Unfortunately, `git add`—which is how you would normally *update* the file—will insist on using the *name you gave the file in the file system*.  Once again, you must fall back on internal Git *plumbing commands* to work around this.  If you need to update that particular file, for instance, you would:

1. run `git hash-object -w -t blob path/to/2021-08-05` to turn the updated file's data into an internal Git object;
2. run `git update-index` with arguments to make Git update the entry for `path/to/2021|08|05` using the hash ID obtained in step 1.

Once all of this is done, you can go back to normal Git commands, because `git commit` makes a new commit from what's in Git's index / staging-area.

The (rather large) drawback here is that you cannot use a lot of normal everyday Git commands:

1. `git pull` is often a no-go because it runs `git rebase` or `git merge`, both of which need to use your working tree (OS-level files).  Run `git fetch` first, then do as much manual work as needed.
2. `git checkout` will fail: you *can* use it, but then you must manually do something about each of the bad file names that are now in Git's index.
3. `git diff` will show differences that include deleting the files with the bad names, and `git status` will show the adjusted-name files as untracked files (because they *are*).
4. `git add` of any changes you need to make to these files is also a no-go; use `git hash-object -w` and `git update-index` instead.
5. `git rebase` and `git merge` become difficult.  You probably *can* deal with them as in steps 2 and 4, but that's painful at best.

Comment: That's an interesting exploration of what's going on under the hood. While this is rightfully scary for beginners, it should be possible to come up with custom "filtered" versions of pull, checkout, etc, that will use the plumbing commands you outlined and provide a high level interface taking care of OP's naming issue. Probably too much work to put into practice though.

Comment: @JanWilamowski: my opinion here is that Git should have a mode/ability to run a mapping (invertible, and also configurable) from index-name to working-tree-name. It should turn this mode on automatically when needed, as in this case, and have it as an option for any other case where it might be useful. But it would be hard to write and test, so I haven't even started on it. :-)

Comment: @torek Thank you for you answear. This directory contains files with performance tests so in fact maybe it would be not needed for me. Maybe there is some simple solution to don't pull this directory to my local machine and don't push this directory (if some news files would be created on my local machine) to the repository?

Comment: If you simply ignore the error from `git checkout` and be sure *not* to tell Git to *remove* the "missing" files, you should be fine, then. That is: make sure not to use `git add .`, `git add *`, and so on.

Comment: @torek Thank you. Is there an option to discard changes related to these problematic files? There is a list of files that could not be pull from original repository on my local machine: [link](https://www.screencast.com/t/Vo0R7y63c2)
These files are visible as deleted by me but I don't want to push that change to the repository. I can't do "Discard change" - in this way file should be restored on my local machine but it's not possible because of illegal characters. Is there any way to "forget" about these changes?

Comment: @marcinłyczko: it's important to realize that the files *are not changed* and *are not deleted*. They still exist in Git's index, in the form they had in the commit in question. What has happened is that Git is unable to extract those files *from* the index, *to* your working tree. Hence any later Git command that *compares* your working tree to Git's index *thinks* **you** deleted the files (from your working tree). You didn't, though.

Comment: There's no "change" that you can "discard" here. Git doesn't *store* changes. Git stores only *files*. Two files that Git thinks should be in your working tree, are not in your working tree. They cannot ever be in your working tree because of their file names. But, as in the answer, Git doesn't build new commits **from** your working tree in the first place.

Comment: Since Git builds new commits from whatever is in Git's index, your job, on your system, is to construct new index contents that reflect what you'd like to have in new commits. As long as you leave those two badly-named files that *are* in Git's index at time T1, in Git's index, so that they are still there at time T2 and T3 and so on, they will still be there when you run `git commit`. That's what the entire answer above is all about: the fact that you just need to arrange the right things in *Git's index*.

Comment: Just make sure that the files are never removed from Git's index, so that `git status` never says that the deletions are "changes to be committed". Git will go on thinking you've deleted the files from your working tree. There's another trick you can use, with `git update-index --skip-worktree`, here, that might help your specific case.